# Final doesn't let me change properties

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm trying to change my components properties. Like setting their alignment to right or left. I have 15 buttons on FlowLayout panel.

```
final FlowLayout exL = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 2, 3);

    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setLayout(exL);

    aligncom.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            int x = aligncom.getSelectedIndex();
            switch (x) {

                case 0: {
                    exL.setAlignment(FlowLayout.LEFT);
                    break;
                }
                case 1: {
                    exL.setAlignment(FlowLayout.RIGHT);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I have this part of my code. "aligncom" is my ComboBox. Since Java wants me to declare my exL variable final, I think I can't change my buttons' properties. Is there any way I can run this code ?

Comment: Well, have you tried running that code? It will run fine. `final` simply says that the reference to the object (if it is an object) cannot change; it does not prevent calling methods on this object, even if said methods mutate it. Mutating an object does not change its reference.

Comment: Yes I tried running this code, but nothing changes. Maybe I did something wrong with my other codes.

Answer (score 3):

> I think I can't change my buttons' properties

No, that's not true. `final` applies to the *variable*, that's all. It doesn't prevent changes to the *object*.

In other words, this would be invalid:

```
exL = new FlowLayout(...); // Trying to change a final variable
```

... but calling `setAlignment` etc is absolutely fine.

Comment: So why It's not working ? When I select RIGHT at my ComboBox, nothing changes. Is my code wrong ? I thought It's about the final declaration.

Comment: @HalilM while I don't know the API you are using, my guess is that you need to `panel.setLayout()` on your object only _after_ you have made modifications to the layout